# retrieving code from array of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi all
i have the following array:

```
   var $status = array('pending' => array('code'=>1,'t_sys_lang'=>248),
                       'approved' =>array('code'=>2,'t_sys_lang'=>214),
                       'rejected' =>array('code'=>3,'t_sys_lang'=>252));
```

how can get t_sys_lang value(248,214....) if i only  have the code value(1,2,...) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getTSLByCode($code) {
   foreach ($GLOBALS['status'] as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v['code'] == $code) return $v['t_sys_lang'];
   }

   return false;
 }

 $t_sys_lang = getTSLByCode( //code );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($status as $v)
    if (in_array($v['code'],$array)) echo $v['t_sys_lang'];
```

Comment: This is sooo ugly: `$array = array...`.

Comment: It should not be pretty, it should be obvious. You can take a pen and draw a smiley next to it ;)